# Linkedin Logout feature

Tags: javascript, jquery, linkedin-api

I'm sort of new to the linkedin developer network, and I got the linkedin javascript api to log a user in.
What i'm wondering about is how to log a user out. i know it has something to do with the IN.User.logout() command, but I don't quite know how to use it.
I want the user to be logged out automatically when the browser closes. So I put the following code in my header:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(window).unload(function() {
        IN.User.logout();
        });

</script>
```

But that didn't do anything.
The tutorial on the linkedin developer network wasn't very good, and I couldn't get a good answer from their forums.
Has anyone played around with the linkedin javascript?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As per [the official docs](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/inauth-inevent-and-inui) (search for "Log the user out") the function signature is:

`IN.User.logout(callbackFunction, callbackScope)`

So you don't just call it and close the browser, you should wait for the `callbackFunction` to return **and then** close the browser.

Also, not letting the user close the window/tab whenever he/she wants sucks. Please think about a `logout` link or something.

Comment: It's like this, I want to make it so that it auto-logs the user out when the user signs off because I just want the user to have the ability to sign into my website (after transferring their linkedin data). But, what I'm confused about is what exactly a callbackFunction would look like in my case, because I really want it to log them out of linkedin when they change the page.

Comment: Ideally you would need to close the browser in the `User.logout` callback, using something like `window.close` for example

Comment: I actually thought about what you said before, and decided that closing the window wasn't a good way to go about it. So i decided that if the user hits the "submit" button when creating an account, it will auto-log them out of the linkedin. But I can't get that to work. Here is the line I used: <a href = "javascript: IN.User.logout(submitForm())">Submit</a>. Where submitForm() is a javascript function that submits the form. When i run it, the form gets submitted, but the user doesn't get logged out... Help?

Comment: Actually it should be `IN.User.logout(submitForm)` (without the parens)

Answer (score 1):

```
  $("#logout").click(function(){
       IN.User.logout(function() {
          window.location = "/logout";
       });
    });
```

This worked fine for me.